# E: Unable to locate package bcmwl-kernelsource

Tags: wireless, broadcom

After installing 14.04 LTS on a HP Probook 6560b  my wifi does not work,  on the web I found this Ask Ubuntu question and proceeded as follows :

```
lspci -vnn | grep Network

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1503] (rev 04)
25:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)

iwconfig

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

lspci -nn  -d 14e4:
25:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
```

Looking in the Broadcomm Wireless Table I found `bcmwl-source` as possible solution and continued

```
sudo update-pciids

sudo add-apt-repository restricted

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install linux-generic

 sudo apt-get install linuxmint-keyring 

sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernelsource

E: Unable to locate package bcmwl-kernelsource
```

Comment: I wanted to add this  to Askubuntu question   55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers.  As I am unfamiliar to this forum it became a new question

Comment: The package name is `bcmwl-kernel-source`.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply but I simply forgot to respond. I corrected my typing error and immediately could install  bcmwl-kernelsource . My Broadcomm wifi is working fine now, thanks a lot

Comment: I would like to close this question, the answer by fkraiem solved my problem